# Import resource based on JNDI in Spring 4.x

Tags: spring

I want to import a resource based on a JNDI entry.

My application-context.xml looks like:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="td.naccms.cods2.config.path" 
    jndi-name="td.naccms.cods2.config.path" expected-type="java.lang.String" 
    default-value="classpath:application-context-persistence.xml" />

<context:property-placeholder />

<import resource="${td.naccms.cods2.config.path}" />
```

And tomcat returns the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [application-context-cods2-web.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'td.naccms.cods2.config.path' in string value "${td.naccms.cods2.config.path}"
```

Note, I do not want to load the resources from a property files because the resourse to be imported is going to change based on the JNDI.

Comment: Remove the jndi lookup. the spring environment already does a lookup in JNDI for you. If you want to specify a default use a `:` to separate that from the placeholder i.e. `${td.naccms.cods2.config.path:classpath:application-context-persistence.xml}`.

Comment: @M.Deinum, thanks it worked for me. Please, enter your comment as answer so I can mark as answered. Also, is there any documentation for reference? The default value was my motivation to use jndi-lookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using placeholders `${...}` you can use a `:` to specify another value in case the expression doesn't resolve (this could even be another placeholder!).

So instead of hacking around with lookups yourself just pass the value using a `:`.

```
<import resource="${td.naccms.cods2.config.path:classpath:application-context-persistence.xml}" />
```

The `Environment` abstraction (used to do resolving of placeholders in newer Spring versions) also checks JNDI for the property next to the System Environment, Property files (loaded through `@PropertySource`) and in a web application the `ServletContext`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.